# Show/hide text by spiting it with html comment in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i split some text in div using html comment. 
Lats say i haw:

```
<div id="id1">Some first text <!--more--> here.</div>
<a id=id1>Show/Hide</a>
<div id="id2">Some second text is <!--more--> right here.</div>
<a id=id1>Show/Hide</a>
```

I wont a jquery or javascript to show or hide text after`<!--more-->`.
Thanks

Comment: Text can be added or removed not shown or hidden. What are you trying to achieve actually ?

Comment: Can you not wrap your text that you want to show/hide in a <span>, which you can then use jQuery on to show/hide?

Comment: Can't get what you want to achieve at the end but `$("#id").html()` will return everything what's in your div (including html comments) and you can do with it what you want.

Comment: Something like blog post but I don't wont to split it with anything else because text inside div will be html formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

Given markup:

```
<div id="id1">Some first text <!--more--> here.</div>
<a>Hide</a>
<div id="id2">Some second text is <!--more--> right here.</div>
<a>Hide</a>​
```

Add the following javascript:

```
//1. On page load, wrap text to be hidden in <span>
$(function() {
    $("div").each(function() {
        var html = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(html.replace('<!--more-->', '<span class="hiddenText">', html) + '</span>');
    });

    // 2. Toggle visibility of span tags when clicking link
    $('a').click(function() {
        if ($(this).html() == 'Hide') {
            $(this).prev('div').children('.hiddenText').hide();
            $(this).html('Show');
        } else {
            $(this).prev('div').children('.hiddenText').show();
            $(this).html('Hide');
        }
    });
});
```

Check my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7GCCa/1/) for a working example.

**UPDATE**: Updated solution to not rely on separate CSS class to hide/show text.

Comment: Thanks man but you forget to call a separate `$('a').html('Show');
    $('a').prev('div').children('.hiddenText').hide();` to hide on load. 
Here is a full script  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7GCCa/15/)